# Non-universal Turing Machines and NP-completness

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Is it true that a given problem is strictly NP-complete iff it's only decidable by universal Turing Machines? Similarly, a problem is in P iff there exists a non-universal Turing machine which solves it? Is it possible to come up with an NP-complete problem which could be solved by a non-universal TM?

Comment: A lot of confusion about those concepts, I suggest this great book: Michael Sipser, "Introduction to the Theory of Computation"

Comment: @Vor Can you specify what exactly am I confusing here? I was thinking a bit about the link between universality and complexity classes.

Comment: Not really. If P!=NP then there a incomplete problems in NP.

Comment: @Patryk: sorry I read the question too quickly and misunderstood it (I need the Sipser more than you :-). Note that you can use "clocked" always halting (so non-universal) Turing machines. For example the class $\mathcal{C}$ of TMs that - on input $x$ run for $2^{|x|}$ steps and halt. In this case there is a non-universal $M \in \mathcal{C}$ that can solve $SAT$. Or a class  $\mathcal{C}'$ of Turing machines that run for $|x|^2$ steps and halt, so there are problems in $P$ that cannot be solved by a TM in that class.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.